Get the colour code to change svg image colour
I am trying to change the colour of an svg but can't find the colour code to change.
I know that I need to change it here fill='%23C03865'.
How do I get the colour code for: #D1FF71
I have tried putting #D1FF71 but no luck.

Not sure about the reason but seems like your SVG is URL encoded so # sign become %23.
It looks like you just might keep the strategy: #D1FF71 in your SVG actually should be %23D1FF71.
